# What does "sore of" mean

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

My question is regarding the usage of the word **sore**

[dictionary.cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sore) describes it as:

**Sore**

> painful and uncomfortable because of injury, infection, or too much use.

It then lists some examples where the usage of the word in that way I am aware of.

But, can we use the very same word with the preposition "of"? So as it would end up looking like this: "sore of" [something]?

For example, could I say:

> I am sore of my lack of money.

Or:

> They are sore of pain because of the injuries.

Or:

> That indigenous tribe is sore of food because of the drought.

Or:

> That guy is in sore need because of the circumstances.

The reason I ask this is because recently I came across a very intelligent person who is known for his great command of the English language. If he said it, he must be right. He wouldn't make such a mistake. Not him.

Comment: What exactly did this person say?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/544746/sour-of-burned-seed-by-ex-prime-minister-of-greece-alexis-tsipras-what-does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are any situations where we use "sore of" in native English. However, it is possible to say "sore because of". Sore is very similar to the word "hurt" in English, so if you are uncertain of how to use it, try substituting it with hurt to see if the sentence makes sense.

Also, note that the last example you give in your post is different from the others. "That guy is in sore need because of the circumstances." The expression "be in sore need of" is grammatically fine, although it is a bit antiquated.

As for the person you mentioned, is it possible that he might have said "*sure* of" and you misheard it? "Sure of" is a very common expression in English.

Answer (score 2):

Could this person have said "sort of"?

Only your last example would make any sense in American English. However, it comes across as antiquated. I'm not sure about other dialects. I have certainly never heard sore of used before.